# Remove undefined value out of an array

Tags: javascript, html

When you check an item, it stores the value into an array. When you uncheck the item, it creates an `undefined` value within the array.

This is not too much of an issue, but having the empty value inside the array counts as a length value which I'm trying to remove. I'm wondering how to remove unchecked array items without storing them as `undefined` inside the array.

```js
const list = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']"));
const specArr = []


function check(e) {
    // a) If checked than add value into array
    if (e.target.checked == true) {
        specArr.push(`${e.target.value}`);
        console.log(specArr);
        // b) If unchecked than remove index from array
    } else if (e.target.checked === false) {
        let index = specArr.indexOf(e.target.value);
        if (index != -1) {
            delete specArr[index]
            console.log(specArr);
        }
    }
}

list.forEach(function (listItems) {
    listItems.addEventListener('change', check)
})
```

```html
<form class="form specialization">
        <p> <u> Select Item </u> </p>
        <br>
                <div class="list">
                        <div class="list-items">
                     
                    <input type="checkbox" name="specialization" value = "Item-1">Item-1
                        <br>
                       
                     <input  type="checkbox" name="specialization" value="Item-2">Item-2
                        <br>   
     
                      <input  type="checkbox" name="specialization" value="Item-3" >Item-3
                            
                         <br>   
                      <input  type="checkbox" name="specialization" value="Item-4" >Item-4
                      
                </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: why don't you `splice` the element from the array instead of deleting and then becoming undefined?
See more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: Thanks @Calvin Nunes. That's what I've used now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `delete`. As per the [`delete` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete):

> Non-configurable properties cannot be removed. This includes properties of built-in objects like Math, **Array**, Object and properties that are created as non-configurable with methods like Object.defineProperty().

`delete` deletes the object property, but does not reindex the array or update its length.

Use [`Array.prototype.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) instead.

```js
const list = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']"));
const specArr = []


function check(e) {
  // a) If checked than add value into array
  if (e.target.checked == true) {
    specArr.push(`${e.target.value}`);
    console.log(specArr);
    // b) If unchecked than remove index from array
  } else if (e.target.checked === false) {
    let index = specArr.indexOf(e.target.value);
    if (index != -1) {
      specArr.splice(index, 1);
      console.log(specArr);
    }
  }
}

list.forEach(function(listItems) {
  listItems.addEventListener('change', check)
})
```

```html
<form class="form specialization">
  <p> <u> Select Item </u> </p>
  <br>
  <div class="list">
    <div class="list-items">

      <input type="checkbox" name="specialization" value="Item-1">Item-1
      <br>

      <input type="checkbox" name="specialization" value="Item-2">Item-2
      <br>

      <input type="checkbox" name="specialization" value="Item-3">Item-3

      <br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="specialization" value="Item-4">Item-4

    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you. @Spectric, if I understand correctly `delete` is creating an undefined value inside the array?

Comment: To the question above ^ `delete` is creating an undefined value inside of the array, the `splice` method is removing it from the assigned index within the array.